# jQuery Delay slideDown using Queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the task to create a function that adds some messages to the page and another to show them in last to first order with a jQuery `slideDown()` effect.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WjaDE/5/)

```
jQuery("#input1").click(function()
{
    //Represents the first function to add the messages
    jQuery.each(["<div>1</div>", "<div>2</div>", "<div>3</div>"],
        function(index, item)
        {
            var jDiv =jQuery(item);
            jDiv.hide();
            jQuery(".parent").prepend(jDiv);
        });

    //represents the second function to show them.
    var jParent = jQuery(".parent");
    jParent.children().reverse().each(function()
    {
        var jThis= jQuery(this);
        jParent.queue( function()
       {
           jThis.slideDown(function()
           {
               jParent.dequeue();
           });

       });
    }); 
});
```

(reverse from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards/5386150#5386150) answer)

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
```

This seems to be an awful bunch of code just to show them one after another. Is there any way to clean up/remove redundant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use function recursion in place of a jQuery queue.

The central piece is the `displayNextHiddenMessagesIn` function. As the name implies, it grabs the next hidden message and displays it.  After the message is displayed, it calls this function again... looping until all messages are visible.

To me, this seems much more readable and easier to maintain. Also, it would be trivial to have a another message parent and reuse this same code (i.e. error messages and information messages).

```
(function($) {

    function createMessageFor(parent, contents) {
        var $parent = $(parent);
        
        for(var content in contents) {
            var $message = newMessage(contents[content]);
    
            $parent.prepend($message);
        }
   
        function newMessage(text) {
            return $("<div />").text(text).hide();
        };
    }
    
    var displayNextHiddenMessagesIn = function(parent) {
        var $parent = $(parent);

        $parent.find('div:hidden:last').slideDown(function() {
            displayNextHiddenMessagesIn($parent);                             
        });
    };

    $("#input1").click(function()
    {
        createMessageFor('.parent', [1,2,3]);
        displayNextHiddenMessagesIn('.parent');
    });
        
})(jQuery);
```

see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/natedavisolds/TP66b/6/

#### Update

Here's what it looks like as a plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.fanDownHiddens = function() {
        return this.each(function() {            
            var $parent = $(this);
        
            $parent.find('div:hidden:last').slideDown(function() {
                $parent.fanDownHiddens();                             
            });
        });
    }            
})(jQuery);
```

And then the onload with the test data.

```
(function($) {
    
    $(function() {
        $("#input1").click(function() {
           setupTestMessages('.parent');
           $('.parent').fanDownHiddens();
        });
    });
    
     function setupTestMessages(parent) {
        var $parent = $(parent),
            testData = [1,2,3];
        
        for(var content in testData) {
            var $message = newMessage(testData[content]);
            
            $parent.prepend($message);
        }
        
        function newMessage(text) {
            return $("<div />").text(text).hide();
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Here's the plugin working: http://jsfiddle.net/natedavisolds/TP66b/12/

Comment: That looks interesting but I'd like to note two things : 1. has message seems unnecessary. if `$nextMessage` is empty nothing will happen. 2. Doesn't seem any real different to mine except that it looks for the last hidden ... or did I miss something. I like that thought though.

Comment: Also the function you've named `createMessageFor` is just a stub for another unrelated ajax method. I only added it to the question so people could see what I was getting.

Comment: @JamesKhoury yep.. you are absolutely right.  I missed that.  I've corrected it above. The `find` is the main difference and not using queue.  I wonder how this would look as a plugin.

Comment: @JamesKhoury I also added the plugin for review.

Answer (score 1):

I skipped the second button for simplicity's sake.

http://jsfiddle.net/WjaDE/7/

```
var jParent = $("#parent"); 
// used an id for the unique element
// cached the element up front
var DURATION = 500;

$("#input1").click(function() {
    $.each(['1', '2', '3'], // simplified the array
        function(index, item) {
            var jDiv = $('<div class=box></div>');
            // added a class to each to improve the css and eliminated the .hide()
            jDiv.html( item );
            jParent.prepend(jDiv);
            jDiv.delay(DURATION * index);
            // used a variable delay to deal with the timing
            jDiv.slideDown(DURATION);
        });
});
```

Comment: The second button was from the jQuery site. I just had it there for testing earlier. The code was in separate sections as they are in different functions. They can't be combined together. But i do like the idea of a Delay.